# Register two jsonsetting in service collection in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, rabbitmq, servicecollection

I have two hosted services, which each service use its own rabbit mq address as you can see :

```json
{
  "RabbitMQOptions": {
    "HostName": "172.23.131.1",
    "VirtualHost": "/",
    "Port": 5672,
    "Username": "**",
    "Password": "***!"
  },
  "RabbitMQOptions1": {
    "HostName": "172.23.39.1",
    "VirtualHost": "***",
    "Port": 5672,
    "Username": "***",
    "Password": "123456"
  }
}
```

I have two hosted service named N4 and Fund and each of them needs its own rabbitmq configuration
Here is the code of my workers:

```
public class N2Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly string QUEUE_CONSUMER_NAME;
    
    private readonly IRabbitMQConsumer _rabbitMQConsumer;
    
    public N2Worker(
        IRabbitMQConsumer rabbitMQConsumer,
        IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _rabbitMQConsumer = rabbitMQConsumer;
    }
}
```

So in my program.cs I added this :

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddRabbitMQ(hostContext.Configuration);
        services.AddHostedService<N2Worker>();
        services.AddHostedService<FundWorker>();
    })
    .Build();
    
await host.RunAsync();
```

So in `AddRabbitMQ` I have this:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddRabbitMQ(
    this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.Configure<RabbitMQOptions>(configuration.GetSection(
        RabbitMQOptions.DefaultSectionName));
    services.AddSingleton<RabbitMqService>();
    
    return services;
}
```

And my `rabbitService` class is this:

```cs
public sealed class RabbitMqService
{
    private readonly RabbitMQOptions _configuration;

    public RabbitMqService(IOptions<RabbitMQOptions> options)
    {
        _configuration = options.Value;
    }

    public IConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        var connection = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            HostName   =  _configuration.HostName,
            Port       = _configuration.Port,
            VirtualHost= _configuration.VirtualHost,
            UserName   =  _configuration.Username,
            Password   = _configuration.Password,
            DispatchConsumersAsync = true
        };
        
        return connection.CreateConnection();
    }
}
```

So as you can see in `AppSetting` I have different addresses, my question is how can I register two RabbitMQ instances with different configuration?

Here is the code of my consumer :

```
public sealed class RabbitMQConsumer : IRabbitMQConsumer, IDisposable
{
    private IModel _channel;
    private IConnection _connection;
    private readonly RabbitMqService _rabbitMqService;
    
    public RabbitMQConsumer(RabbitMqService rabbitMqService)
    {
        _rabbitMqService = rabbitMqService;
    }
}
```

I want to inject rabbitConsumer into each workes with different configuration I mean N4 uses RabbitMQOptions and fund uses RabbitMQOptions1

Comment: That's not valid JSON, or at the very least the second one overrides the first one.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two sections with the same name in your config name, so you'll have to name them differently, for instance:

```json
  "RabbitMQOptions1": { ... },
  "RabbitMQOptions2": { ... }
```

Next, you'll have to register the two services seperately, while loading their individual configuration, for instance:

```cs
var options1 = Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQOptions1").Get<RabbitMQOptions>();

services.AddSingleton<RabbitMqService>(_ => new RabbitMqService(options1));

var options2 = Configuration.GetSection("RabbitMQOptions2").Get<RabbitMQOptions>();

services.AddSingleton<RabbitMqService>(_ => new RabbitMqService(options2));
```

Last, as `RabbitMqService` now depends on `RabbitMQOptions` rather than `IOptions<RabbitMQOptions>`, you need to change its constructor:

```cs
public sealed class RabbitMqService
{
    private readonly RabbitMQOptions _configuration;

    public RabbitMqService(RabbitMQOptions options)
    {
        _configuration = options;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Steven Would you please let me know how can I tell rabbitmqservice to which option should be selected?And Another question is how can I access the instance of service in my hosted Service ?

Comment: @EhsanAkbar The code here already tells you how each service is configured, did you read it 
thoroughly?

Comment: Oh wait, you mean your hosted services each take a `RabbitMqService` as a parameter? You haven't shown that in your question.

Comment: @DavidG Yes I read the code , this answer doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @DavidG yes exactly ,each hosted service needs its own rabbit mq instance with different configuration .

Comment: You need to use the code above but move it up a level. Use this method for example: `.AddHostedService<N2Worker>((provider, builder) => { .... })`

Comment: @DavidG would you please give me more details ?

Comment: Your update makes it even more confusing. Is `IRabbitMQConsumer` the same as `RabbitMqService`? Please be more careful, with 6.5k rep I would expect a more fully formed question.

Comment: @DavidG Yes I injected RabbitMqService to rabbitConsumer,Sorry I added update

Comment: Hi @EhsanAkbar, at this point, it is unclear to me in which way you actually want to structure your code. Can you update your question (once more) and add an example of what object graph you wish the container to compose? What I mean by that is: show -using the good old `new` keyword- how the set of objects would look if you would create them by hand. For instance: `new A(new B(new X())), new C(new Y(), new Z()))`.

Comment: @Steven Of course ,I updated the code ,would you please take a look

Comment: @Steven As a note I want to inject rabbitConsumer into each workes with different configuration I mean  N4 uses RabbitMQOptions and fund uses RabbitMQOptions1